# How to call a label to display if the score is below e.g.:90 points?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Im making a word game, there are two possible labels "Perfect!" which shows only when the score is 100 and "Correct!" when the score is below 100,

But I'm having trouble calling the "Correct!" label when the score goes below 100!

```
- (IBAction)btncheck:(id)sender {

NSString *answer = [_textbox.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){

}
else

if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) {
    _keyboard.hidden = YES;
    _textXclear.hidden = YES;
    //Perfect button
    [_closeone setHidden:NO];
    [_wrongone setHidden:YES];

    score = MAX (score +100, 0);
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];

   coins = coins +5;
   if (score == 100) coins = 8;
    if (score == 0) coins = 0;
    if (score == 4) coins = 4;
    if (score == 3) coins = 3;
    if (score == 2) coins = 2;
    if (score == 1) coins = 1;
    [coinsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", coins]];

}
else {
    [_wrongone setHidden:NO];
    score = MIN(score -5, 0);

    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score: %d", score]];
    // animation that shakes the image (qimage)


   closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";

}
```

The label is called

```
closeonechange.text = "Correct!";
```

How will I call it to show when the score is below 100, so 99 & below must show the "correct!" label?

Comment: Put `closeonechange.text = @"Correct!";` outside the if else and check `if (score < 100)` to display it.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on that please, because I think it may be correct... So a bit more detail, worded right will help a ton?

Comment: if (score < 100) score = closeonechange.text = @"Correct!"; like this??? it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
if([answer isEqualToString:@""]){
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}

if (score < 100) {
    closeonechange.text = "Correct!";
} else {
    closeonechange.text = //set else condition text
}
```

Comment: You may want to do score <= 100. So it always shows correct when the score is exactly 100.

Answer (score 0):

In your if else statement hide/show it:

```
if ([answer isEqualToString:@"q"]) { //Score >100 display perfect
    // Your code...
    closeonechange.text = "Perfect";
}
else { //Score < 100 display correct
    // Your code...
    closeonechange.text = "Correct";
}
```

//Extended

If you use just one label to display text instead of hide/show just change the text, see edited above.

Comment: The thing is I'm using one label to display 2 words (correct)&(perfect)